# Can't stop my webpage from wrapping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple Javascript program that should prevent my webpage from wrapping when decreasing the size of the browser window.  It works on one of my webpages but not on a new page I am trying to design.

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("[class~='floatNoWrap']").each(function () {
$(this).css("width", $(this).outerWidth());
});

});
```

CSS:

```
.floatNoWrap
{
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class = "floatNoWrap">

HTML WEBPAGE CONTENT ...

</div>
```

Comment: Is this the new page?  I'm not seeing the problem in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRfhK/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `white-space:nowrap;`

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Xxg8/)**

Comment: Yep, don't use Javascript (and definitely not jQuery) if simple CSS will take care of it.